# TypeError: $(...).sideNav is not a function

Tags: javascript, materialize

I am trying to use Materialize theme to make a side bar in JSF with `Spring`. And I imported the Materialize's `js` and `css`, but it comes out an error `TypeError: $(...).sideNav is not a function`. I don't know why, and I tried in a normal HTML file, and it works.

What is the reason that I get this error and how to fix it?

The structure of the page:

```
<h:head>
<title><h:outputText value="#{msg.title}" /></title>

   <!-- Import Materialize css -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./themes/materialize/css/materialize.min.css"/>

 <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="./themes/materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="./themes/materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>
 <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>


  (function($){
  $(function(){

      $('.button-collapse').sideNav('show');

  }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
</script>

</h:head>

  <h:body onload="init();">


<!--<table id="Table_01" class="Table_01">-->
<table id="WholeFunctionPageLayoutTable" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" width="100%"
        border="0px">

        <tr id="WholeFunctionPageWidthSpacer" >



            <td>
            <!--<table class="Table_SASC_03">-->
                <table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" style="margin-left:0px; padding-left:0px;" border="0px">
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td>
                            <ui:include src="MenuTemplate.xhtml" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>                                                                       
                </table>
            </td>
            <!-- End Page Left Menu Navigation Section -->

        </tr>

 </table>
 </h:body>

</html>
```

The JSF file `menuTemplate.xhtml` that trying to make a side bar.

```
<ui:composition>

<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
   <li><div class="userView">
      <div class="background">
        <img src="../img/EN_logo.jpg"/>
      </div>
        <a href="#!user"><img class="circle" src="../img/EN_logo.jpg"/></a>
        <a href="#!name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
        <a href="#!email"><span class="white-text 
                                 email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
       </div></li>
   <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With I 
     con</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
   <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
   <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
   <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
 </ul>
      <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse">menu</a>
 </ui:composition>
```

The error message:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 problems in your code:

**1:** MaterializeCSS is not compatible with jQuery 3, So you have to use some older version of JQuery. Try 2.x.x:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**2:** In your comments, where you are importing scripts it is clearly mentioned to import jQuery before Materialize.js

```
<!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
```

and you are still importing it after. So switch those lines, **import jQuery before materialize.js**

Answer (score 6):

Materialize is compatible with jQuery3. You just have to load jQuery first before you load materialize.min.js.

Answer (score 5):

For .sideNav() to work, **MaterializeCSS v1.0.0 is not compatible** with jQuery v3 or v2, So you have to use older version of MaterializeCSS. **Try 0.x.x**: it worked for me!

eg:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">`

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>`

Comment: don't know if it were true at the time of this comment. But materialize 1.0.0 is now perfectly running with jQuery 3.4.1, the solution was to load jQuery first.

Answer (score 3):

.sideNav() has been renamed .sidenav() in v1.0.0 see https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html

Comment: Yes, but you're only partly correct. You need to check with the jquery version you're using along with the materializecss.min.js version.

Answer (score 2):

The order of loading is important, as stated above. JQuery 3.3.1 works with Materialize 1.0.0:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This is the solution I came up with.

```
setTimeout(function (){
  $('.button-collapse').sideNav('show');
},1000)
```

The problem is that you are accessing the jQuery element before it is rendered. Wait a second.

Comment: Good idea, using `setTimeout`, but sometimes it fail.

Comment: You can call this upon .ready event of either document itself or the parent/container element of this element

Answer (score 1):

**Update: Oct-2017:** `Materialize v0.100.2`  works with jQuery `v3.2.1`, provided you need to put them in the right order:

Below code snippet is taken from MaterializeCSS site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem. It *is* because jQuery must be loaded before the Materialize.min.js file. Once I switched the order, everything worked fine. No problem with getting this working with jQuery 3 as long as the order is correct.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript initialization use sidenav() instead of sideNav()

Change this:

```
(function($){
   $(function(){
    $('.button-collapse').sideNav('show');
 });
})(jQuery);
```

To this:

```
(function($){
 $(function(){
  $('.sidenav').sidenav();
 });
})(jQuery);
```